# Regular expression parsing partial renders with JMeter ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, regex, jmeter

I'm attempting to use the regex extractor to parse the VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION variables. This works quite well for simple GET requests, however, there are some forms that use ajax postbacks and as a result return partial renders

The issue is the formatting of the VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION in these renders:

```
       |hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|/wEPDwUKMT..... long string continues here

       |hiddenField|__EVENTVALIDATION|/wEdAEj... long string
```

How can I modify my regex extractor to fit this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest switching from regex extractor to one of below:

1. [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
2. [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

Both of them are not so fragile as Regular Expression Extractor and designed to work with HTML. Using Regular Expressions to parse HTML isn't a very good option as it evidenced by [Stackoverflow epic thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) so consider switching to XPath/CSS approach.

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for more details.